# Firebase - How to get all items in an array in Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a function that fetches all items in friend_requests array and prints them.

I've found some tutorials for JavaScript, but I'm trying to do this in Python and as a beginner I don't quite understand how to achieve that. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: SO is not a tutoring service, you need to learn the basics elsewhere. When you've tried to implement something, you can post here if it's not working and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: [Please use a MCVE format if you want answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself:

```
def get_friend_requests(user):
    requests = db.collection("users").document(user).get()
    if requests.exists == True:
        requests_dict = requests.to_dict()
        print("Friend requests:", requests_dict["friend_requests"])
    else:
        print("User not found")
```